# difference between corrplot and pheatmap of correlation matrix? how to make it consistent between the two

Tags: correlation, r-corrplot, pheatmap

I noticed that the correlation plot made by corrplot is different from the one made by pheatmap.
original data:
[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ucCFx8enqdakYmdFkTJpHa6_38xSS9r6jfXudVBAYBs/edit#gid=1046708306)

correlation matrix in corrplot,

```
count = read.csv('data_here.csv') 
mtx = cor(count, method = 'kendall')

corrplot(mtx, method="color", tl.cex = .35, 
         order="hclust", hclust.method = 'complete')
```

[image]

would like to add dendrogram on the axes of the plot, but had not figured it out using ccorrplot...
So instead I tried pheatmap,

```
mtx %>% pheatmap(
fontsize = 3,
clustering_method = 'complete')
```

[image]

It is obvious that the two packages cluster differently. For example, the gene RSPO3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inspired by this post,
https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/clustering-using-correlation-as-distance-measures-in-r/

figured it out in this way!

```
pheatmap(mtx,
fontsize = 3,
clustering_distance_cols = as.dist(1 - mtx),
clustering_distance_rows = as.dist(1 - mtx)
)
```